# "Operator mismatch" error in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, graph

I'm creating a transpose of the graph `v` and saving it in `g2`. Both `v` and `g2` are same type, so `g2` will hold the transpose of the graph.

Below, `v` is of `vector<int>v[1000]`. It consists a adjacency list representation of a graph.

```
vector<int> v[10000] = ...; // input: some matrix
vector<int> g2[10000]; // output: transposed matrix

for(int u=0;u<N;u++) //N is the number of vertices
    for(vector<int>::iterator it=v[u].begin();it!=v[u].end();it++) 
      g2[v[*it]].push_back(u);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
prog.cpp:74:8: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::vector<int> [10001]' and 'std::vector<int>')
   g2[v[*it]].push_back(u);
    ^
```

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: The problem is `g2[v[*it]]`.    `*it` is of type `int`  (okay).  `v[*it]` is of type `std::vector<int>`, and you are trying to use it as an index into array `g2` for which indices can only be of integral type, not a vector of `int`.     That's the problem.   Without knowing why you rattled off that code, or what you are trying to achieve by rattling it off, nobody can offer suggestions on what you need to do   (mindreading over the internet is a VERY rare skill).

Comment: oh sorry I didn't add that. Actually I'm creating a transpose of the graph v and saving it in g2. both v and g2 are same type so g2 will hold the transpose of the graph(i think).

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> g2[10000];
for(int u=0;u<N;u++) //N is the number of vertices
{ 
      for(vector<int>::iterator it=v[u].begin();it!=v[u].end();it++) 
      {
         g2[u].push_back(*it);
      }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: sorry bro I didn't downvote. Here I want to  create a transpose, of the graph v, and save it in g2.  But I think your code will just create a replica of v? sorry I didnt mention transpose earlier!